# Cascade-like deletion on a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have a `@ManyToOne` relation between `Workpackage`s and `Project`s. Where a project can have one to many workpackages.

My `Workpackage` entity refers to the `Project` one like such:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = ProjectEntity.class)
private ProjectEntity project;
```

Therefore each line in my `Workpackage` table references the `id` of a certain project.

But when I try to delete a project, I get a foreign key constraint (which makes sense, since my workpackage depends on a project, and should be deleted before the former is deleted).

But a `cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE` won't work since I am deleting my project and not my `Workpackage`. Would there be a way to delete the `Workpackage` related to a certain project upon its deletion?

Being new to `Hibernate`, nothing obvious comes to mind other than going through every `Workpackage` and deleting them one by one.

Comment: **explicit remove** can be option , http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/delete

Answer (score 0):

**ON DELETE CASCADE** : if you delete a project row in table Project the engine will delete as well the related workPackages. This can used to make automatic cleanups on secondary tables.

1. When declaring schema, do the following thing

   `alter table Workpackage add constraint constraintName 
   foreign key (id) references Project(id) on delete cascade`
2. you will have to set child's object as null explicitly.

   `for (Workpackage child : project.getWorkpackages()) {
       child.setProject(null);
   } 
   session.delete(OwningSide);`

Comment: How can that be achieved via `Hibernate`? I'm not sure I understand your two points.

Comment: Please follow the 2nd point alone to do this in hibernate, Before deleting project, retrieve all workPackages and set Project as null explicitly. Hibernate make sure that, when deleting Project, it will delete workPackages automatically.